# Facebook share only works with message inside

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I'm making a facebook share on my website but it is not working correctly.

I won't share if I dont type a message with it.

It worked once for me without message.

**HTML:**

```
 <a href="#" class="btn faceb orange darken-4" id="btn_ingresar" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.faceb').attr('href','https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed? app_id=894298903965098 &display=popup&caption=HETLANDVAN.EU &name=Nederland, het land van...' + $('.modal-body').text()+ '&description=Klik hier om ook alles over Nederland te weten te komen! &picture=http://i.imgur.com/ROOilRC.png &link=http://hetlandvan.eu &redirect_uri=http://hetlandvan.eu');

$('.modal-body').text() is just a random word.
```

http://hetlandvan.eu

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - [it seems to work without a message](http://i.imgur.com/LGY51Nr.png). I tried this [a few times](http://i.imgur.com/hIq5Edm.png)...

Comment: In any case, once the share dialog is displayed to the user, the control is passed to Facebook - if there is an issue with the shared post at this stage it might be a problem on Facebook's side.

Comment: If you can reproduce this issue, you should file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs. Works for me though.